# Magento 2: How can i configure magento shipping option?

Tags: magento2, shipping, backend, system-config

[image]

i have tried to access "magento shipping" shipping method but i can not able to get any require credentials and also not found any support about pricing list if its a paid service.

Is there anyone who have already used this method then please share your knowlegde.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info in the below dev docs link o how to configure Magento Shipping.
[Setup Magento Shipping](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/magento-shipping-setup.html)

Comment: Thanks , i showing that link but i can not find any link for access shipping account.

Comment: Click the "Request Shipping Account" link on the configuration

Comment: Its redirect me on https://magento.com/ page. I have already login into my account. Is there need to any special or premium account ?